# How can I make my Button Divs all have the same width?

Tags: css

I'm trying to find the answer to a problem I have. What I have is many buttons and I want them to appear down the page and all be the same width. I have the following code and CSS. However they don't appear to be the full width. What I want ideally is them to be a width equal to the enclosing DIV. I also want the text to appear centered which it does now. Can anyone tell me why the buttons all appear different widths?

I have the following code:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div class = "abc" >
    <a class = "btn"  href="/test" title="Classes">Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class = "abc" >
    <a class = "btn"  href="/test" title="Classes">Test  sadfadsfdsafsadfsa</a>
  </div>
  <div class = "abc" >
    <a class = "btn"  href="/test" title="Classes">Test  afds</a>
  </div>
  <div class = "abc" >
    <a class = "btn"  href="/test" title="Classes">Test asdfdsafadsfdsfasdfsadfdsf</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.abc {
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 190px;
}

a.btn {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 180px;
}
```

I created a fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRQaa/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to specify the width of an `a` tag you need to set it to `display: block`

Answer (score 1):

remove the class="abc" div, they are not needed.
Give the .btn class a `display: inline-block;` (or just `block`, but I dislike it).

Answer (score 1):

Link (a) elements are inherently inline elements, which ignore width declarations.

By applying a `display:block` to a.btn, it will accept your width declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify width for block-level elements.  To correct it, you can add a `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` to your a.btn class

Comment: They'd want `block` because the elements are all floated left already for whatever reason.

Comment: Yep, just mentioned inline block for general reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block;` to `a.btn`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a.btn display:block;
since, by default, a are inline elements.